# Convert json to array using Perl

Tags: json, perl

I have a chunk of json that has the following format:

```
{"page":{"size":7,"number":1,"totalPages":1,"totalElements":7,"resultSetId":null,"duration":0},"content":[{"id":"787edc99-e94f-4132-b596-d04fc56596f9","name":"Verification","attributes":{"ruleExecutionClass":"VerificationRule"},"userTags":[],"links":[{"rel":"self","href":"/endpoint/787edc99-e94f-4132-b596-d04fc56596f9","id":"787edc99-e94f-...
```

Basically the size attribute (in this case) tells me that there are 7 parts to the content section. How do I convert this chunk of json to an array in Perl, and can I do it using the size attribute? Or is there a simpler way like just using decode_json()?

Here is what I have so far:

```
my $resources = get_that_json_chunk();  # function returns exactly the json you see, except all 7 resources in the content section
my @decoded_json = @$resources;

foreach my $resource (@decoded_json) {
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
my $deserialize = from_json( $resources );
my @decoded_json = (@{$deserialize});
```

I want to iterate over the array and handle the data. I've tried a few different ways because I read a little about array refs, but I keep getting "Not an ARRAY reference" errors and "Can't use string ("{"page":{"size":7,"number":1,"to"...) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use"

Comment: `my $obj = decode_json($json); print "$_->{id}\n" for @{$obj->{content}};`

Comment: In your first attempt, you're trying to treat a string as an array reference. That's not going to work (obviously). Your second attempt is closer, but now you're treating a hash reference as an array reference. You need to access the `content` key in the resultant hash reference and dereference _that_ as an array reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you to Matt Jacob:

```
my $deserialized = decode_json($resources); 
print "$_->{id}\n" for @{$deserialized->{content}};
```